# EF4 adding a summary database view(readonly)

Tags: entity-framework-4, view

I am using EF4 and SQL Server 2008. I have a summary View in the database and I tried to add it to edmx file by Update Model from Database. However it gives an error demanding a primary key on the view.However my view has no primary key and is read only- How to add the view??

The error is

```
Message 6   The table/view 'SurveyReports.dbo.vw_responserate' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.   F:\SurveyReports\SurveyReports\SurveyReports\SurveyReports\DAL\Reports.edmx 0   0   SurveyReports
```